# Direct creation of AndroidViewModel

Tags: android

I am manually copying a backup sqlite database into `getDatabasePath(OfferingsDatabase.DB_NAME)`. Once the backup is completely copied, I call my reset Database function defined in the RoomDatabase:

```
public static OfferingsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), OfferingsDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                    .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void resetDatabase(Context context) {
    getInstance(context).close();
    INSTANCE = null;
}
```

That is, this code is executed once the database is fully copied:

```
 OfferingsDatabase.resetDatabase(getContext());
 setupViewModel();
```

where the last method is:

```
private void setupViewModel() {
    OfferingsViewModelFactory factory = new OfferingsViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication());
    OfferingsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(OfferingsViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getOfferings().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (List<OfferingEntity> offeringEntries) -> {
        mOfferingsAdapter = new OfferingsAdapter(getContext());
        mOfferingsAdapter.setOfferings(offeringEntries);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mOfferingsAdapter);
    });
}
```

**The problem is**, the old data still resides in my view. It is not replaced by the new data. I was hoping that `new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(OfferingsViewModel.class)` will call `OfferingsDatabase.getInstance()` in order to fetch the new database entry, but it doesn't.

**What have I tried?** I tried to directly create my OfferingsViewModel via

```
 OfferingsViewModel viewModel = new OfferingsViewModel(getActivity().getApplication())
```

in order to force the constructor to be called which will in turn call `getInstance()`. **And indeed, this works!**

But I suspect it is not good to practise to directly create the ViewModel. So is there a good practice?

EDIT:

This is my Factory:

```
public class OfferingsViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

private final Application mApplication;

public OfferingsViewModelFactory(Application application) {
    mApplication = application;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    return (T) new OfferingsViewModel(mApplication);
}
```

}

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class OfferingsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private OfferingsRepository mOfferingsRepository;
private LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> mListLiveOfferings;

public OfferingsViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    mOfferingsRepository = new OfferingsRepository(application);
    mListLiveOfferings = mOfferingsRepository.getAllOfferings();
}

public LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> getOfferings(){
    return mListLiveOfferings;
}

public void checkPoint() {
    mOfferingsRepository.checkPoint();
}
```

}

My repository:

```
public class OfferingsRepository {
private OfferingsDao mOfferingsDao;
private LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> mAllOfferings;
private Application mApp;

public OfferingsRepository(Application application) {
    mApp = application;
    OfferingsDatabase db = OfferingsDatabase.getInstance(mApp);
    this.mOfferingsDao = db.getOfferingsDao();
    mAllOfferings = mOfferingsDao.loadAllOfferings();
}

public LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> getAllOfferings() {
    return mAllOfferings;
} 
}
```

And the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface OfferingsDao {
// OFFERINGS
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
long insertOffering(OfferingEntity offeringEntity);

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
int updateOffering(OfferingEntity offeringEntity);

@Query("DELETE FROM " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + OfferingEntity.DATE + " LIKE :date")
int deleteOffering(String date);

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + OfferingEntity.DATE + " DESC")
LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> loadAllOfferings();

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + OfferingEntity.DATE + " LIKE :date")
LiveData<OfferingEntity> loadOfferingByDate(String date);

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + OfferingEntity.TYPE + " = '" + OfferingsRecyclerViewFragment.COMBINATION + "'")
LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> loadCombinationOfferings();

@RawQuery
int checkpoint(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery);
}
```

Comment: When do you run that code, that resets the database? Apparently not at app start, because then the viewmodel would not have been created yet. Is this a one-time thing our something that happens on a regular basis?

Comment: In the settings the user can restore his database from a server. The database is downloaded and copied to the database path. Once that is done, I am resetting the database. So this scenario does not happen very often - only when the user migrates to a new device or restores his database.

Comment: Since you're using Room, should you not have a LiveData<Offering> getOfferings() in your OfferingDao and would that not automatically return the new data, when it changes in the database?

Comment: No, it doesn't... the db is still connected to the old DB.

Comment: Can you post the code of the viewmodel (at least the database relevant parts) and the factory?

Comment: Updated the code with my ViewModel classes. Take a look. Hope you can help...

Comment: By looking at your code, you want to reset the database and call the fresh data again from the ViewModel. Isn't it @to_sam?

Comment: @BrahmaDatta: That is correct. The reason is, I copied a new DB into the DB-Directory.

Comment: To get the fresh data we need to invalidate the ViewModel factory data source @to_sam. I have done it in my project, I had the same issue that the data remained same when I didn't invalidate

Comment: @BrahmaDatta: Can you give me an example of what exaclty you mean with invalidate?

Comment: I mean I used the recycler view data and I tried to get the latest data by using ViewModel creating new instance but I didn't get the new data. So as I searched for answers I got to know if we invalidate the source we get the latest data. @to_sam

Answer (score 0):

In all these layers you have quite a lot of local variables that complicate the view on what happens. I guess, the main culprit in your case is `OfferingsDatabase db = OfferingsDatabase.getInstance(mApp);` in `OfferingsRepository`. Here you hold on to the old instance of the database.